# How to fix incorrect colors with Plotly when column contains 'NA'

Tags: r, r-plotly

When columns contain 'NA' values, then Plotly changes the colors that I assign for the lines and markers. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you! (I am using R version '3.6.0 (2019-04-26)' and Plotly version ‘4.9.0’)

The data for the first graph contains some 'NA' values for the 'trust_ecb' column which is plotted on the y-axis. The colors for the lines and markers are incorrect, i.e. different than the colors assigned in the code.

However, when I then recode the 'NA' values to '70', and plot the graph, then the colors are correct.

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5c80.jpg) with incorrect colors ('trust_ecb' column contains NA).
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki3Xq.jpg) with correct colors ('trust_ecb' column does not contain NA)

```
#Creating dataframe
trust_eur_cyp <- structure(list(year = c(2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
                    2015L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2009L, 
                    2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L), group = structure(c(4L, 
                                                                                   4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Cypriots", "EU-15", "EU-25", "Greek-Cypriots", 
                                                                                                               "Turkish-Cypriots"), class = "factor"), trust_ecb = c(53.2, 50.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                     44, 33.7, 10.9, 23.2, 19.3, 29.1, 42.1, 36.6, 41.8, 48.1, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                     NA, 48.8, 48.7, 42.7, 35.1, 17.5, NA, NA)), row.names = c(6L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L), class = "data.frame")




#Creating plots
library(plotly)

plot_trust_ecb_cyp <- plot_ly(trust_eur_cyp, y = ~trust_ecb, x= ~year, color = ~group, type = "scatter",
                          mode = "lines+markers",
                          line = list(color = factor(trust_eur_cyp$group, labels = c("FFCF00","9702A7","00A876")), width = 3), 
                          marker = list(color = factor(trust_eur_cyp$group, labels = c("FFCF00","9702A7","00A876")), size = 6),
                          legendgroup = ~group, showlegend = T) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = "%  'Tend to Trust'", titlefont=list(size=20), range = c(0,80), tickfont = list(size = 16)),
     xaxis = list(title = "", dtick = 2, tickfont = list(size = 16)))  

#Recoding 'NA' to '70' to show that now colors in plots are correct
trust_eur_cyp$trust_ecb[is.na(trust_eur_cyp$trust_ecb)] <- 70

#Rerun plotly code above.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a vector with the colors for the different groups as desired. Then assign `colors` to it in `plot_ly`. Since there are unused factor levels, for clarity, I dropped these first and used the same 3 colors you have used. I believe this works with your missing values.

```
trust_eur_cyp$group <- droplevels(trust_eur_cyp$group)

pal <- c("#9702A7", "#00A876", "#FFCF00")

plot_trust_ecb_cyp <- plot_ly(trust_eur_cyp, y = ~trust_ecb, x= ~year, color=~group, colors = pal,
                              type = "scatter",
                              mode = "lines+markers",
                              line = list(width = 3), 
                              marker = list(size = 6),
                              legendgroup = ~group, showlegend = T) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = "%  'Tend to Trust'", titlefont=list(size=20), range = c(0,80), tickfont = list(size = 16)),
         xaxis = list(title = "", dtick = 2, tickfont = list(size = 16)))
```

[image: plot_ly with NAs]

Comment: Great, thanks. Do you know why that would be? Shouldn't both of the codes produce the same graph?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure. When I looked around for clues I came across this on github: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1126. I thought maybe it might be related to how `plot_ly` deals with `NA` and separates groups with traces, in combination with factor levels that were not being used. But I really am not sure about the whole thing.